# How store all DataTable's data in javascript array after column search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have tables exactly as described in https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html. My code structure is exactly the same (please see the full code and demo using the link).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Now I want to return all records (rows) in the table after performing the search operation, either through `console.log()` or save the data in javascript array.

For example after I search **Accountant** in `Position` column, I want to get the whole data stored in javascript array

[image]

```
[[Airi Satou,Accountant,Tokyo,33,2008/11/28,$162,700],
[Garrett Winters,Accountant,Tokyo,63,2011/07/25,$170,750]]
```

I have tried something like `console.log( table.row( this ).data() );` but didn't work. How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding your `console.log(table.rows().data())` inside this block `if ( that.search() !== this.value )` and after `.draw()`?

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez yes tried that, nothing printed on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paolo's answer, I got an insight of what should I do. My answer is the alternative to Paolo's answer. Instead of returning an array everytime I type on the search box, I add a submit button after applying filter to my table. So the returned array will be the same as the data shown on the table after filtering.

```
var table = $('#tableViewer').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 50, 100, -1], [5, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "dom": 'lfrtipB',  // component position
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Run',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        plainArray = table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).data().toArray();
                        for (var x = 0; x < plainArray.length; x++) {
                            console.log(plainArray[x]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this adding this code after `.draw()`

```js
table.rows().$('tr', {"filter":"applied"}).each( function () {
  console.log(table.row(this).data())
});
```

Sample Result:

- Multiple

```js
Array(6) [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "33", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ]
Array(6) [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "35", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ]
Array(6) [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "30", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ]
Array(6) [ "Zenaida Frank", "Software Engineer", "New York", "63", "2010/01/04", "$125,250" ]
```

- Single

```js
Array(6) ["Zenaida Frank", "Software Engineer", "New York", "63", "2010/01/04", "$125,250"]
```

I also created a codepen just in case you wanted to try:
[Individual column searching (text inputs)](https://codepen.io/paouriel/pen/OJVagqr)

Comment: Thank you. 1 question if u dont mind, what if I want to save only the result after I finish my typing? I realized that in your code, it will return something everytime I type on the search box.